# Google VR video doesn't load

Tags: javascript, video, google-vr

I'm using Google [VR View for the web](https://developers.google.com/vr/concepts/vrview-web) to load in a 360 video. But when I load the video, it says **Error, Render: video load error: [object event]**

[image]

This is what the console shows:

[image]

When I load the example video from Google's url, it works like a charm: https://storage.googleapis.com/vrview/examples/video/congo_2048.mp4

This is the code I'm using (with the same video, but stored on my site):

```
<div id="vrview"></div>

<script src="//storage.googleapis.com/vrview/2.0/build/vrview.min.js"></script>

<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', onVrViewLoad)
    function onVrViewLoad() {
        var vrView = new VRView.Player('#vrview', {
            video: 'video/congo.mp4',
            is_stereo: true 
        });
    };
</script>
```

[Edit] Even with the full link to the video on my domain, the video still doesn't work.

[Edit 2] This is the file structure:

- css
- img
- js
- video

  - congo.mp4
- index.html

Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: So how did you solve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:

Set CORS headers - see http://enable-cors.org/server.html for server specific details

Comment: When you said that it works when you load the example video from Google's url, was that in your code or just loading it up in your browser? If it is the latter does Google's url work in your code?

Comment: If I load the Google URL in the code, the video displays correctly.

Comment: Are you serving the video up with the same security - it might not accept loading from an insecure (e.g. http) source when the webpage itself is secure (https).

Comment: I'm not an expert at that, but the webpage is https.

Comment: Is your webserver available on the public internet, and accessible to Google's servers? Make sure you're not using something like localhost/192.168.1.X/127.0.0.1, and that your ports are properly forwarded. This is because it actually creates an iframe in which it needs to access your site for the video.

Comment: If you're using "Web server for Chrome" try ticking the box under advanced settings labeled "Set CORS headers".

Comment: Also the stuff I was saying about localhost/192.168.X was wrong, it does work with that when CORS headers are set properly

Comment: I think you're on to something! :-) Should "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" be included in the .htaccess in order to get it to work? It's getting a little technical for me now.

Comment: If you're using apache, then add:
`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`
to .htaccess

Comment: Make sure you reload apache to update the settings - do `sudo service apache2 reload`

Comment: Check if there's an option to restart the server/contact them - if not it's likely that they automatically restart their servers soonish so maybe wait a while - in the mean time for development you could try running a local webserver - this extension works well: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en

Comment: Alrighty, I am using xampp for the local testing, but restarting doesn't help :-(

Comment: Hmm..

Try adding `LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so` and change the header to always - `Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`

Answer (score 3):

Use two required parameters (width, height), then it works well without setting CORS headers.

However, I am now struggling to solve similar problem in the case of handling local or youbute 360 video. i.e. I can run just a provied example file but not real 360 files. Do you have any progress?

My post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41312283/how-to-play-youtube-360-videos-using-vrview-web

cf link. http://vcml.cafe24.com/humble.php

```js
    window.addEventListener('load', onVrViewLoad);

    //It works
    function onVrViewLoad() {

      var vrView = new VRView.Player('#vrview', {
     width: '100%',
     height: 600,
     video: 'http://storage.googleapis.com/vrview/examples/video/congo_2048.mp4',
     
     is_stereo: true,
      });
      
      //Now I'm struggling. Not working
      var vrView1 = new VRView.Player('#vrview1', {
     width: '100%',
     height: 600,
     
     video: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/OkLa7jkFXpU',
     //video: 'http://vcml.cafe24.com/video.mp4',
     
     is_stereo: false,
      });
    }
```

```html
 Congo Video
  <div id="vrview"></div>
  
 Youtubu Video
  <div id="vrview1"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort! The video didn't work on a lot of browsers and mobile devices, so I had to switch to another player. Sorry for the late reaction by the way!

Answer (score 0):

Do not use this script `<script src="//storage.googleapis.com/vrview/2.0/build/vrview.min.js"></script>`,You have use `<script src="vrview-master/build/vrview.js"></script>` from the sample zip file.